# Declaring callable variables in a for loop in python

Tags: python, variables, loops

I have a problem with my python code. I am writing a GUI in python using tkinter that displays several blocks with about 10 rows with 4 radiobuttons, an entry field and a scale in each row. Code below

```
    for r,v,mi,ma,i in zip(self.radiobuttonShapes, self.valueShapes, self.minShapes, self.maxShapes, range(1,10)):
        ttk.Label(self.Shape, text="Shape " + str(i)).grid(column=0, row=i)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self.Shape, text="Off", variable=r, value=1, command=self.resetAllRadiosShape).grid(column=1, row=i)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self.Shape, text="Max", variable=r, value=2, command=self.resetAllRadiosShape).grid(column=2, row=i)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self.Shape, text="Min", variable=r, value=3, command=self.resetAllRadiosShape).grid(column=3, row=i)
        ttk.Radiobutton(self.Shape, text="Approx", variable=r, value=4, command=self.resetAllRadiosShape).grid(column=4, row=i)
        ttk.Entry(self.Shape, textvariable=v).grid(column=5, row=i)
        ttk.Scale(self.Shape, from_=mi, to=ma, variable=v).grid(column=6, row=i)
```

This mostly works fine.
My problem arises when i want to add an label to put it all into and expand that label with another row including and entry field and a scale, to use with the approx option.

My problem consists of not being able to create the variables on the fly and be able to access them by their methods afterwards.

Might not be clear to understand, but i think the dummy code below makes it easier. I want to be able to make parts of it inactive (the approx field when approx is not chosen).

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    self.outerLabel$(i) = ttk.Label(self.Shape).grid(row=i)
    self.upperLabel$(i) = ttk.Label(self.outerLabel$(i)).grid(row=0)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabel$(i)).grid(column=0)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabel$(i)).grid(column=1)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabel$(i)).grid(column=2)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabel$(i)).grid(column=3)
    ttk.Entry(self.upperLabel$(i)).grid(column=4)
    ttk.Scale(self.upperLabel$(i)).grid(column=5)
    self.lowerLabel$(i) = ttk.Label(self.outerLabel$(i)).grid(row=1)
    ttk.Entry(self.lowerLabel$(i)).grid(column=0)
    ttk.Scale(self.lowerLabel$(i)).grid(column=1)
    self.lowerLabel$(i).configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for this, instead of dynamic variable names, the setup code would look something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.outerLabels = {}
    self.upperLabels = {}
    # whatever else is currently in __init__()
```

And wherever the code is from your question:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    self.outerLabels[i] = ttk.Label(self.Shape).grid(row=i)
    self.upperLabels[i] = ttk.Label(self.outerLabels[i]).grid(row=0)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabels[i]).grid(column=0)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabels[i]).grid(column=1)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabels[i]).grid(column=2)
    ttk.Radiobutton(self.upperLabels[i]).grid(column=3)
    ttk.Entry(self.upperLabels[i]).grid(column=4)
    ttk.Scale(self.upperLabels[i]).grid(column=5)
    self.lowerLabels[i] = ttk.Label(self.outerLabels[i]).grid(row=1)
    ttk.Entry(self.lowerLabels[i]).grid(column=0)
    ttk.Scale(self.lowerLabels[i]).grid(column=1)
    self.lowerLabels[i].configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: I tried to use a dict, but python tells me i cant store callable variables in a dict.

Comment: @wadum - Can you add the error you are seeing to your question?  You should be able to have functions and callable classes as dict values, although possibly not as dict keys.

Comment: @ F.J I am sorry, must have wrote something else wrong, works beautifull now :) Thank you!